# noisy circuit by openfermion

Tags: programming, simulation, noise, openfermion

I am working on designing quantum error mitigation algorithms for simulating chemical systems. Therefore, a necessary component is to add noisy to the ideal circuit when using a quantum simulator. But I notice there is no such features in the official documentation of openfermion.
Is there a way to add noise to the circuit in openfermion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that OpenFermion interoperates with cirq to provide many features that are not specific to quantum chemistry. You can add noise to your circuits like this

```
noisy = ideal.with_noise(cirq.depolarize(p=0.01))
```

where `ideal` and `noisy` are instances of `cirq.Circuit`. Alternatively, you can use a simulator such as [`cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/cirq/sim/density_matrix_simulator.py) which allows you to add noise to the simulation, e.g.

```
noise = cirq.ConstantQubitNoiseModel(cirq.depolarize(0.01))
noisy_simulator = cirq.DensityMatrixSimulator(noise=noise)
```

See [this notebook](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/docs/noise.ipynb) for more details and code examples for both approaches.